# Excel VBA Error Calling Sub From Control Form Box

Tags: excel, error-handling, vba

I'm in the process of building a very-rushed and multi-tiered macro in VBA that is supposed to do the following things:

1. User chooses number 1-4 on starting sheet; additional sheets 1 - 4 appear and call the first module to format the worksheets (Works successfully)
2. User navigates to the first of the 4 worksheets and answers question 1, then 2-4 populate (works successfully)
3. User fills out questions 2-4 (maybe more depending on criteria) and clicks the button (control form, not active-x) to run a macro from another sub (This is where it fails)

If I run it from the module itself, the code that the button is assigned to works. If I run it from the button, it doesn't follow through with the secondary sub calls (Example: It adds "Hood 1" to a range value like it should, but then it doesn't follow-up with the macro call to format the column listed under "Hood 1"

Add runbox:

```
    'Removes the old run button
Wks.Shapes.Range(Array("RunBox")).Delete
Set RunBoxRng = Nothing
Set RunBoxRng = Ans1Rng.Offset(3, 3)

'Adds button to populate the rest of the questions
With RunBoxRng.Resize(3, 2)
    Set RunBox = Wks.Buttons.Add(.Left, .Top, .Width, .Height)
End With
With RunBox
    .Name = "RunBox"
    .Characters.Text = "Answer All Questions to the Left Then Click Here"
    With .Characters(Start:=1, Length:=48).Font
        .FontStyle = "Bold"
        .Size = 12
    End With
    .Display3DShading = True
    If Ans1Rng.Value > 1 Then
        .OnAction = Nothing
        .OnAction = "PopulateQuestions.PopulateQuestions"
    End If
    If Ans1Rng.Value = 1 Then
        .OnAction = Nothing
        .OnAction = "Populate1HoodQs.Populate1HoodQs"
    End If
    .Locked = False
End With
```

That will successfully pull from the other modules, but won't let those modules call their secondary subs.

Secondary sub call example:

```
If Not HoodRng1 Is Nothing Then
    HoodRng1.Value = "Hood 1"              'Works
    Call PopulateHood1Qs.PopulateHood1Qs   'Doesn't work
End If
If Not HoodRng2 Is Nothing Then
    HoodRng2.Value = "Hood 2"              'Works
    Call PopulateHood2Qs.PopulateHood2Qs   'Doesn't work
End If
If Not HoodRng3 Is Nothing Then
    HoodRng3.Value = "Hood 3"              'Works
    Call PopulateHood3Qs.PopulateHood3Qs   'Doesn't work
End If
If Not HoodRng4 Is Nothing Then
    HoodRng4.Value = "Hood 4"              'Works
    Call PopulateHood4Qs.PopulateHood4Qs  'Doesn't work
End If
```

I haven't slept in around 36 hours because of this thing, and I can't find a way to get it to work without having to manually run it from the module. And it also makes it so that the FormatMerging sub I have can't be called for them either. PLEASE SOMEONE SAVE ME, WHAT AM I DOING WRONG?!

Edit: First part of the secondary PopulateHood1Qs1 module:

```
       Set HoodRng1 = Nothing
Set Ans2Rng = Nothing
Set Ans3Rng = Nothing
Set Ans4Rng = Nothing
Set HoodRng1 = .UsedRange.Find(What:="Hood 1", LookAt:=xlWhole)
Set Ans2Rng = .UsedRange.Find(What:="General Questions").Offset(4, 4)
Set Ans3Rng = Ans2Rng.Offset(2)
Set Ans4Rng = Ans3Rng.Offset(2)

'Defines hood question strings
HoodQ = "What is the length of Hood 1?"
ASPQ = "How many appliance specific coverages are required?"
ZODQ = "Is the Hood protected by continuous Linear Heat Detection?"
ZOPQ = "How many Zones of Protection are there?"
DuctQ = "How many ducts are in Hood 1?"

'Defines question ranges
Set Q1Rng1 = Nothing
Set Q2Rng1 = Nothing
Set Q3Rng1 = Nothing
Set Q4Rng1 = Nothing
Set Q5Rng1 = Nothing
Set Ans1Rng1 = Nothing
Set Ans2Rng1 = Nothing
Set Ans3Rng1 = Nothing
Set Ans4Rng1 = Nothing
Set Ans5Rng1 = Nothing
Set Q1Rng1 = HoodRng1.Offset(2)
Set Q2Rng1 = Q1Rng1.Offset(2)
Set Q3Rng1 = Q2Rng1.Offset(2)
Set Q4Rng1 = Q3Rng1.Offset(2)
Set Q5Rng1 = Q4Rng1.Offset(2)
Set Ans1Rng1 = Q1Rng1.Offset(, LineSz)
Set Ans2Rng1 = Q2Rng1.Offset(, LineSz)
Set Ans3Rng1 = Q3Rng1.Offset(, LineSz)
Set Ans4Rng1 = Q4Rng1.Offset(, LineSz)
Set Ans5Rng1 = Q5Rng1.Offset(, LineSz)

'Adds questions 1 & 2
Q1Rng1.Value = "1. " & HoodQ
Q2Rng1.Value = "2. " & ASPQ

'Determines where to add the next question
Set NextQRng = Q3Rng1

'If adding linear heat
If Ans2Rng.Value = 2 Then
    NextQRng.Value = ZODQ
    Set NextQRng = NextQRng.Offset(2)
End If

'If adding ZOP
If Ans3Rng.Value = 2 Then
    NextQRng.Value = ZOPQ
    Set NextQRng = NextQRng.Offset(2)
End If

'If adding ducts
If Ans4Rng.Value = 2 Then
    If NextQRng.Offset(-2).Value <> DuctQ And NextQRng.Offset(-4).Value <> DuctQ And NextQRng.Offset(-6).Value <> DuctQ Then
        NextQRng.Value = DuctQ
    End If
End If

'Adds numbers
If Q3Rng1.Value <> "" Then Q3Rng1.Value = "3. " & Q3Rng1.Value
If Q4Rng1.Value <> "" Then Q4Rng1.Value = "4. " & Q4Rng1.Value
If Q5Rng1.Value <> "" Then Q5Rng1.Value = "5. " & Q5Rng1.Value

'Defines box ranges
Set ASPRng1 = Nothing
Set ZODRng1 = Nothing
Set ZOPRng1 = Nothing
Set DuctRng1 = Nothing
Set ASPRng1 = Ans2Rng1
Set ZODRng1 = HoodRng1.EntireColumn.Find(What:="Is the Hood protected by continuous Linear Heat Detection", LookAt:=xlPart).Offset(, LineSz)
Set ZOPRng1 = HoodRng1.EntireColumn.Find(What:="Zones of Protection", LookAt:=xlPart).Offset(, LineSz)
Set DuctRng1 = HoodRng1.EntireColumn.Find(What:="How many ducts", LookAt:=xlPart).Offset(, LineSz)

'Names Hazard 1
If InStr(1, Wks.Name, "1") > 0 Then
    If Not ASPRng1 Is Nothing Then ASPRng1.Name = "H1ASPRng1"
    If Not ZODRng1 Is Nothing Then ZODRng1.Name = "H1ZODRng1"
    If Not ZOPRng1 Is Nothing Then ZOPRng1.Name = "H1ZOPRng1"
    If Not DuctRng1 Is Nothing Then DuctRng1.Name = "H1DuctRng1"
End If

'Names Hazard 2
If InStr(1, Wks.Name, "2") > 0 Then
    If Not ASPRng1 Is Nothing Then ASPRng1.Name = "H2ASPRng1"
    If Not ZODRng1 Is Nothing Then ZODRng1.Name = "H2ZODRng1"
    If Not ZOPRng1 Is Nothing Then ZOPRng1.Name = "H2ZOPRng1"
    If Not DuctRng1 Is Nothing Then DuctRng1.Name = "H2DuctRng1"
End If

'Names Hazard 3
If InStr(1, Wks.Name, "3") > 0 Then
    If Not ASPRng1 Is Nothing Then ASPRng1.Name = "H3ASPRng1"
    If Not ZODRng1 Is Nothing Then ZODRng1.Name = "H3ZODRng1"
    If Not ZOPRng1 Is Nothing Then ZOPRng1.Name = "H3ZOPRng1"
    If Not DuctRng1 Is Nothing Then DuctRng1.Name = "H3DuctRng1"
End If
    'Names Hazard 1
If InStr(1, Wks.Name, "4") > 0 Then
    If Not ASPRng1 Is Nothing Then ASPRng1.Name = "H4ASPRng1"
    If Not ZODRng1 Is Nothing Then ZODRng1.Name = "H4ZODRng1"
    If Not ZOPRng1 Is Nothing Then ZOPRng1.Name = "H4ZOPRng1"
    If Not DuctRng1 Is Nothing Then DuctRng1.Name = "H4DuctRng1"
End If

'Adds ASP box
With ASPRng1
    If Wks.Shapes.Range(Array("ASPBox1")) Is Nothing Then Set ASPBox1 = Wks.DropDowns.Add(.Left, .Top + 0.75, .Width - 0.5, .Height - 1.6)
End With
With ASPBox1
    .Name = "ASPBox1"
    .ListFillRange = "ZeroToFour"
    If InStr(1, Wks.Name, "1") > 0 Then .LinkedCell = "H1ASPRng1"
    If InStr(1, Wks.Name, "2") > 0 Then .LinkedCell = "H2ASPRng1"
    If InStr(1, Wks.Name, "3") > 0 Then .LinkedCell = "H3ASPRng1"
    If InStr(1, Wks.Name, "4") > 0 Then .LinkedCell = "H4ASPRng1"
    .DropDownLines = 9
    .Display3DShading = True
    .Locked = False
    .Deselect
End With

'Adds ZOD box
With ZODRng1
    If Wks.Shapes.Range(Array("ZODBox1")) Is Nothing Then Set ZODBox1 = Wks.DropDowns.Add(.Left, .Top + 0.75, .Width - 0.5, .Height - 1.6)
End With
With ZODBox1
    .Name = "ZODBox1"
    .ListFillRange = "YesNo"
    If InStr(1, Wks.Name, "1") > 0 Then .LinkedCell = "H1ZODRng1"
    If InStr(1, Wks.Name, "2") > 0 Then .LinkedCell = "H2ZODRng1"
    If InStr(1, Wks.Name, "3") > 0 Then .LinkedCell = "H3ZODRng1"
    If InStr(1, Wks.Name, "4") > 0 Then .LinkedCell = "H4ZODRng1"
    .DropDownLines = 9
    .Display3DShading = True
    .Locked = False
    .Deselect
End With

'Adds ZOP box
With ZOPRng1
    If Wks.Shapes.Range(Array("ZOPBox1")) Is Nothing Then Set ZOPBox1 = Wks.DropDowns.Add(.Left, .Top + 0.75, .Width - 0.5, .Height - 1.6)
End With
With ZOPBox1
    .Name = "ZOPBox1"
    .ListFillRange = "ZeroToFour"
    If InStr(1, Wks.Name, "1") > 0 Then .LinkedCell = "H1ZOPRng1"
    If InStr(1, Wks.Name, "2") > 0 Then .LinkedCell = "H2ZOPRng1"
    If InStr(1, Wks.Name, "3") > 0 Then .LinkedCell = "H3ZOPRng1"
    If InStr(1, Wks.Name, "4") > 0 Then .LinkedCell = "H4ZOPRng1"
    .DropDownLines = 9
    .Display3DShading = True
    .Locked = False
    .Deselect
End With

'Adds Duct box
With DuctRng1
    Set DuctBox1 = Wks.DropDowns.Add(.Left, .Top + 0.75, .Width - 0.5, .Height - 1.6)
End With
With DuctBox1
    .Name = "DuctBox1"
    .ListFillRange = "DuctList"
    If InStr(1, Wks.Name, "1") > 0 Then .LinkedCell = "H1DuctRng1"
    If InStr(1, Wks.Name, "2") > 0 Then .LinkedCell = "H2DuctRng1"
    If InStr(1, Wks.Name, "3") > 0 Then .LinkedCell = "H3DuctRng1"
    If InStr(1, Wks.Name, "4") > 0 Then .LinkedCell = "H4DuctRng1"
    .DropDownLines = 9
    .Display3DShading = True
    .Locked = False
    .Deselect
End With

'Adds default values
If Not ASPRng1 Is Nothing Then ASPRng1.Value = 1
If Not ZOPRng1 Is Nothing Then ZOPRng1.Value = 2
If Not ZODRng1 Is Nothing Then ZODRng1.Value = 1
If Not DuctRng1 Is Nothing Then DuctRng1.Value = 1

'Defines range for new button
Set RunBoxRng1 = Nothing
Set RunBoxRng1 = Q5Rng1.Offset(2, 1)

'Adds button to populate the rest of the questions
With RunBoxRng1.Resize(2, 2)
    If Wks.Shapes.Range(Array("RunBox1")) Is Nothing Then Set RunBox1 = Wks.Buttons.Add(.Left, .Top, .Width, .Height)
End With
With RunBox1
    .Name = "RunBox1"
    .Characters.Text = "Answer All Fields and Click to Populate"
    .Display3DShading = True
    .OnAction = "PopulateHood1Qs.PopulateHood1Part2"
    .Locked = False
    .Deselect
End With

'Realigns
With RunBoxRng1.Resize(2, 2)
    RunBox1.Top = .Top
    RunBox1.Height = .Height
    RunBox1.Width = .Width
    RunBox1.Left = .Left
End With
```

I've uploaded a copy of it in all of of various/glorious forms of failure. [Uploaded here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B29iJExWAL75cTVnMkwyU2p0WEk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: what is `PopulateHood1Qs.PopulateHood1Qs` is it modulename.subname? if yes then that's the issue. Use different names for modules and subs. what do you mean by not working? do you get any error? why doing this  `onaction = nothing`?

Comment: 'PopulateHood1Qs.PopulateHood1Qs' is a modulename.subname, so I got really excited and changed them and I'm still getting the same results. It's not that it's populating an error, it's that it's just not populating. The initial module the form box calls is 'PopulateQuestions', which then in turn determines how many ranges to add (HoodRng1/2/3/4) and then designates those ranges and calls separate modules 'PopulateHood1Qs.PopulateHood1Qs(1)'. The '.onaction = nothing' was added as a desparate attempt to reset the range to get it to switch between the two modules and it worked so I kept it.

Comment: If there's no error on calling (eg) `PopulateHood1Qs`, but it doesn't seem to do anything, then most likely the problem is in that procedure (and the others which also do nothing).  You don't show that code so it's not possible to offer any further suggestions.

Comment: Put some breakpoints in `PopulateHood1Qs` and see where it reaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Tim Williams; the problem is probably with **Populate1HoodQs** and **PopulateQuestions**.  I tested the code and had no  problems.  Have you tries putting breakpoints in the **Populate1HoodQs** and **PopulateQuestions**  to see if they are actually being called or not?

The module name is optional. What if `Ans1Rng.Value = 0` or `Ans1Rng.Value = ""`?  I agree with

I get an error on `.Display3DShading = True`.

```
Const RUNBOX_NAME = "RunBox"

On Error Resume Next
wks.Shapes.Range(RUNBOX_NAME).Delete
On Error GoTo 0

Set RunBoxRng = Ans1Rng.Offset(3, 3)

'Adds button to populate the rest of the questions
With RunBoxRng.Resize(3, 2)
    Set RunBox = wks.Buttons.Add(.Left, .Top, .Width, .Height)
End With
With RunBox
    .Name = RUNBOX_NAME
    .Characters.Text = "Answer All Questions to the Left Then Click Here"
    With .Characters(Start:=1, Length:=48).Font
        .FontStyle = "Bold"
        .Size = 12
    End With
    '.Display3DShading = True
    .OnAction = IIf(Ans1Rng.Value = 1, "Populate1HoodQs", "PopulateQuestions")
End With
```

Comment: It's set up so that ans1rng.value can only be 1, 2, 3, or 4. I put breakpoints throughout PopulateQuestions, but when I run it from the module it works, it's just when I try to run from the boxes that it doesn't work.

Comment: By boxes do you mean buttons?

Comment: Yes the buttons, sorry. Specifically that one "RunBox" button.

Comment: Do you have to keep adding and deleting the button?  Could you just hide it?  Have you tried assigning the macro manually to the buttons?  if so, does the macro run that way?

Comment: This was originally intended to delete and re-add the sheet as it ran each time, but I've only recently found out the sheets can't be deleted. So theoretically it doesn't have to be deleted each time. And yes I tried created a new button and assigning it manually and it still gives me the same thing. I know I must be doing something monumentally stupid, but I haven't found out it is.

Comment: ....the ones that say Answer All Questions to the Left populate little red/grey boxes for Hoods 1/2/3/4 whatever the hood count is? And they look like they're properly merged?

Comment: Worksheets Hazard 1 RunBox has ` 'Macro Workbook 2.xlsm'!PopulateQuestions.PopulateQuestions` assigned to it instead of `PopulateQuestions.PopulateQuestions1`

Comment: Whoops, I knew I missed one. Sorry about that. But the others populate the Hood 1/2/3/4 sections properly for you?

Comment: So I downloaded the one from my shared drive instead of using the one on my desktop and for some reason now it's working, so whatever changes you've inspired me to make have at some point fixed the problem/maybe this was all just user error/lack of sleep. I applaud your patience and aide, and I apologize for being a n00b. Thanks for putting up with me :D